# How to open multiple windows in a queue, each window waiting for previous to close?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a primitive notifications system.

This is how I show my window:

```
var data = new NotificationData {
    Title = "New order",
    OrderId = "1"
}
var notification = new NotificationWindow(data);
    Activated += (s, e) => { notification.Owner = this; };
    notification.Show();
```

Then the `NotificationWindow` just displays provided data. But if there are multiple notifications, they all stack in one spot, I need them to appear after previous is closed.

I tried to use `ShowDialog()` instead and it did work - but the `MainWindow` hangs when notification is open. Running it in a different thread using `Task.Run()` causes notifications not to appear.

Comment: So you need a NotificationQueue in the MainWindow.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I'm not sure what you mean. I did try making a queue for notifications, the problem is notifications can be interacted with and can be viewed for an undefined amount of time, I can't simply wait specified time until it closes

Comment: So what happens if the most front notification stays open for a long time? will the others be ignored?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I want them to appear one after another (if user closes most front notification, next one in queue would appear). I was thinking that I should make them react to events, but I'm not sure where I should begin with it

Comment: Attach a handler for the Window's Closed event, where you show the next one.

Comment: @Clemens Well, that does sound very promising - at this stage I think I don't need to be concerned by performance, but would passing a list of `NotificationData` with ~20 entries significantly affect display speed?

Comment: Passing a list where? Besides that you would certainly pass it by reference, that question seems poinless.

Comment: @Clemens I thought about making `data` a list of `NotificationData` entries. This list would act as a simple queue - notification will display the first entry and for each notification displayed, the first entry is removed until there is nothing in the list.

Comment: Sure, but there is no reason to pass the queue to a NotificationWindow. Pass the head element instead. Take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to register to the closed event and then check if another notification is queued.

The key is the `ShowOrQueueNotification` which checks if there is a notification present or not. If there is one present, queue the new one and when the notification is closed, you need to check if there is one queued.

I've made an example to show how to use a queue for it:

---

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestNotificationQueue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNotificationQueue"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="158.868" Width="266.385">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Yellow" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <StackPanel Margin="20">
                <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxMessage" Width="192" />
                <Button Content="ShowNotification" Width="128" Height="24" Click="Button_Click" Margin="8"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestNotificationQueue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Queue<NotificationInfo> _notificationQueue = new Queue<NotificationInfo>();
        private NotificationWindow _currentNotificationWindow;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowOrQueueNotification(new NotificationInfo(TextBoxMessage.Text));
        }

        private void ShowOrQueueNotification(NotificationInfo notificationInfo)
        {
// ----->   If no notification is presented, create one.
            if (_currentNotificationWindow == null)
            {
                _currentNotificationWindow = new NotificationWindow(notificationInfo);
                _currentNotificationWindow.Closed += CurrentNotificationWindow_Closed;
                _currentNotificationWindow.Show();
            }
            else
// ----->       queue it.
                _notificationQueue.Enqueue(notificationInfo);
        }

        private void CurrentNotificationWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// ----->   This is crucial, you need to set the current to null, else all new notification will be queued and never be presented.
            _currentNotificationWindow = null;

            if(_notificationQueue.Count > 0)
                ShowOrQueueNotification(_notificationQueue.Dequeue());
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Notification.cs**

```
namespace TestNotificationQueue
{
    public class NotificationInfo
    {
        public NotificationInfo(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }

        public string Message { get; }
    }
}
```

---

**NotificationWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestNotificationQueue.NotificationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNotificationQueue"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="NotificationWindow" Height="93.117" Width="239.4">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBoxMessage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**NotificationWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestNotificationQueue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NotificationWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NotificationWindow : Window
    {
        public NotificationWindow(NotificationInfo notificationInfo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBoxMessage.Text = notificationInfo.Message;
        }
    }
}
```